# Disable request logs in terminal

Tags: sails.js

Is it possible to turn off sails request logs. Like I'm trying to not see the example pasted below. Because when I run my integration tests, these logs get in the way of the report.

```
<- PUT /api/v1/entrance/login                 (361ms 200)
 |  The requesting user agent has been successfully logged in.
 |  
 |  Under the covers, this stores the id of the logged-in user in the session as the `userId` key.  The next time this user agent sends a request, assuming it includes a cookie (like a web browser), Sails will automatically make this user id available as req.session.userId in the corresponding action.  (Also note that, thanks to the included "custom" hook, when a relevant request is received from a logged-in user, that user's entire record from the database will be fetched and exposed as `req.me`.)
 |  
 ° 
<- GET /api/v1/user/me/overview/subscribe     (26ms 200)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sails hook.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-apianalytics

Read documentation, u can edit logs or disable some of them, or just uninstall hook.

Run `npm uninstall sails-hook-apianalytics` on root of project and then lift sails.

Comment: Perfect thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for almost a month on-and-off.

Comment: I didn't want to uninstall that hook, so what I ended up doing was disabling it in my `sails.lift` config of test suite: `hooks: { grunt: false, apianalytics: false },`

Answer (score 2):

To disable requests logging only in production, it may be convenient to just add the [configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-apianalytics#configuration) to `config/env/production.js`, leaving the `routesToLog` property as an empty array, thereby no logging routine will be bound to any event, so there'll be no overhead whatsoever.

Comment: Interesting idea matpop

Answer (score 1):

If you check the sails.js [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-log) about logs, you can change the level of logs as you want. There are several ways to accomplish that, but i prefer to put the log level in the env file, because some logs are not needed in production but in development make sense and is ease to do this:

```js
// config/env/production.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  log: {
    level: 'debug'
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and I still see these "request-level" logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you set test cases similar with me.

I added configuration in my `./test/lifecycle.test.js`.

'./lifecycle.test.js` is addressed in https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing#?lifecycletestjs

When I call `sails.lift()` in it, I added this configuration as below:

```js
  sails.lift(
    {
      log: { level: 'silent' },
      apianalytics: { routesToLog: [] },
    },
```

And then, I could see only mocha log.